# SQLite Entity Framework query to return next available date

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, linq-to-sql

I have this query where from appointment table I want to get the next date for that customer.

```
 from customer in db.Customers
 from order in db.Appointment
     .Where(o => customer.CustomerId == o.CustomerId)
     .DefaultIfEmpty()
Select new {NextAppointment = "How to get this date?"}
```

Class `Appointment`:

```
public class Appointment
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string AppointmentInstructorName { get; set; }
    public DateTime LessonDate { get; set; }
   public long CustomerID {get; set;}
    public string AppointmentLessonAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Class `Customer`:

```
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
    public string Suburb;
    public string NextAppointment;
    public string Mobile;
    public string DrivingLicenceNo;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return $"{FirstName} {LastName}"; }
    }

    public int ID;
```

When a customer signs up, they will be given a time against an instructor for a lesson, and on the home page, I want to show the next available appointment

--Update--

this is what i have written. will this affect performance or should be ok? still finding out though how can i got the top 1 from appointment table

```
   var obj = (from a in Appointment
   orderby a.LessonDate ascending
   where a.LessonDate>= DateTime.Now
   select a);

   var d = (from c in Customer
   join o in obj on c.ID equals o.CustId into ps
   from o in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
   select new { c, o.LessonDate});
```

Comment: Why doesn't `Appointment` have one `DateTime` property instead of these awkward strings for Date and Time? That's such a hassle in querying!

Comment: this is the first time i was playing with sqlite and wasn't sure how it will behave but you can treat it like a datetime (i will change the model to reflect that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it working with this:

```
var s = (from i in Customer
let p = Appointment.Where(p2 => i.ID == p2.CustId && p2.LessonDate >= DateTime.Now).OrderBy(ta => ta.LessonDate).FirstOrDefault()
select new
{
i, p.LessonDate
});
```